# Modify a mysql query please

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have this query:

```
SELECT p.ID
     , p.post_title
     , tr.trid
     , tr.language_code
  FROM ts_posts AS p
  LEFT 
  JOIN ts_icl_translations AS tr 
    ON tr.element_id = p.ID 
   AND tr.language_code IN ('en', 'us')
 WHERE p.post_status='publish' 
    AND p.post_type IN ('teaching-resource', 'post')
 ORDER 
     BY p.post_date DESC;
```

It returns list of posts. Some posts have one lang version - en, others have for example 2 lang version - en and us.

[image: See the screenshot below]

**Help me to modify that query to return row in condition:
if post has a one lang return en row
if post has more lang version return us (or it should a param of query)**

Result should be like that:

[image: See screenshot below]

**UPD:**
I've modified the query. It returns exactly what I'm looking for without subqueries and having.

```
SELECT p.ID
     , p.post_title
     , tr.trid
     , tr.language_code
  FROM ts_posts AS p
 LEFT 
  JOIN ts_icl_translations AS tr 
    ON tr.element_id = p.ID 
   AND tr.language_code IN ('en', 'us')
   LEFT JOIN ts_icl_translations AS tr2
   ON tr.trid = tr2.trid AND tr2.language_code = 'us'

   LEFT JOIN ts_posts AS p2 On p2.ID = tr2.element_id
 WHERE p.post_status='publish' 
    AND p.post_type IN ('teaching-resource', 'post')
    AND tr.language_code = IFNULL(tr2.language_code, 'en')
 ORDER 
     BY p.post_date DESC;
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN. It's generally regarded as being harder to grasp then its LEFT counterpart

Comment: @Strawberry ok, modified to LEFT JOIN

Comment: It seems like GL has this, but if you're still struggling, see See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I found the solution, thanks

Comment: Feel free to post an answer, and accept it. That's how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.ID
     , p.post_title
     , tr.trid
     , tr.language_code
  FROM ts_posts AS p
 LEFT 
  JOIN ts_icl_translations AS tr 
    ON tr.element_id = p.ID 
   AND tr.language_code IN ('en', 'us')
   LEFT JOIN ts_icl_translations AS tr2
   ON tr.trid = tr2.trid AND tr2.language_code = 'us'

   LEFT JOIN ts_posts AS p2 On p2.ID = tr2.element_id
 WHERE p.post_status='publish' 
    AND p.post_type IN ('teaching-resource', 'post')
    AND tr.language_code = IFNULL(tr2.language_code, 'en')
 ORDER 
     BY p.post_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is "us" if it exists, otherwise any other language.  How about this?

```
select p.ID, p.post_title, tr.trid, tr.language_code
from ts_posts p left join
     (select tr.element_id,
             coalesce( max(case when tr.language_code = 'us' then 'us' end),
                       max(tr.language_code)
                     ) as language_code
      from ts_icl_translations tr
      group by tr.element_id
     ) tre
     on tre.element_id = p.ID left join
     ts_icl_translations tr
     on tr.element_id = p.ID and tr.language_code = tre.language_code
where p.post_status = 'publish' and
      p.post_type in ('teaching-resource', 'post') 
order by post_date desc;
```

It gets the preferred language, with "us" first and any language second.  It then joins back to the translations to get more detail.

Comment: Hi, Gordon, thank you for reply. Your query returns: https://screencast.com/t/rf9iQ7fBhd4y

Comment: I probably need to use "having with condition"

Comment: I used this query: `SELECT p.ID
     , p.post_title
     , tr.trid
     , tr.language_code,
     count(tr.trid) as lang_count
  FROM ts_posts AS p
 RIGHT 
  JOIN ts_icl_translations AS tr 
    ON tr.element_id = p.ID 
   AND tr.language_code IN ('en', 'us')
 WHERE p.post_status='publish' 
    AND p.post_type IN ('teaching-resource', 'post')
    GROUP BY trid
 ORDER 
     BY p.post_date DESC;` It return a nearly what I need result. She the screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/EFbJNkRla6dC

Comment: @mrKirill . . . Not the `having`, but the `group by`.